# Specify timestamp on each packet in Scapy?

Tags: python, scapy

With [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), when I create a packet and write it to a `pcap` file, it sets the timestamp of the packet to the current time.

This is my current usage. `1335494712.991895` being the time I created the packet:

```
>>> a = Ether()/IP(src='1.1.1.1',dst='2.2.2.2')/TCP(sport=1337,dport=31337)
>>> wrpcap('single-tcp-packet.pcap', a)

# tcpdump -tt -r single-tcp-packet.pcap
reading from file single-tcp-packet.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
1335494712.991895 IP 1.1.1.1.menandmice-dns > arennes-651-1-107-2.w2-2.abo.wanadoo.fr.31337: Flags [S], seq 0, win 8192, length 0
```

How can I specify my own timestamp per packet?

I have seen timestamp mentioned in the docs for setting the `TCP` timestamp, but it doesn't seem to make a difference to the actual `pcap` timestamp.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah! Found it.

Simply:

```
>>> a.time = 1234567890
>>> wrpcap('single-tcp-packet.pcap', a)

# tcpdump -tt -r single-tcp-packet.pcap
reading from file single-tcp-packet.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
1234567890.000000 IP 1.1.1.1.menandmice-dns > arennes-651-1-107-2.w2-2.abo.wanadoo.fr.31337: Flags [S], seq 0, win 8192, length 0
```

Comment: Gerald, if you would like to maybe see a human readable version of that time stamp in scapy I use this after from datetime import datetime print datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%Y-%m-$d %H:%M:%S').split(' ')[1]

Comment: @dc5553 this no longer works these days. Just a heads up.

'EDecimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer